How to override Microsoft Edge's (on iOS) CSS Dark Mode override?
Microsoft Edge for iOS has a browser "Dark mode" theme selector (Light, Dark, System default).
Under "Light" mode or "System default"** (**where iOS's appearance is set to "Light"), everything happens as you might expect. Yay.
But, things get weird when the browser is under "Dark" mode (or "System default" mode="Dark"). Edge for iOS seems to be hellbent on super-overriding the web themes to be in "Dark mode" no matter what.
For example: Try visiting Stack Overflow with the Stack Overflow theme set to "dark", as well as your Edge for iOS browser theme set to "dark". The appearance is super weird, because Edge doesn't respect Stack Overflow's opinion of a "dark theme".
Another example, I have a simple theme selector for the user to choose (Auto, Light, Dark). "Auto" behaves by respecting the browser/OS preferences. It's fine. "Dark" also works fine. But when I try to use the "Light" theme, the Edge for iOS browser super-overrides it to what it believes a dark theme ought to be. To put it simply: Edge in dark mode will override the user's choice to use a light theme override. Bad Edge! Bad!
I think this is incorrect behaviour, and ought to be reported and fixed by Microsoft, but we are developers… so we don't want to sit and wait around for that to happen.
Has anybody found a way to override Edge's dark theme super-override?
EDIT: 2024-06-26
So, this problem seems to be related to Chromium browsers that might have been embracing this "forced dark mode" experimental flag. There's a blog about it with the Samsung Browser from a few years ago… where some intended solutions include having the following meta tag:
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">

To indicate that the webpage supports both light and dark themes. In principle, browsers that have a matching theme preference are NOT supposed to override the colours.
Alternatively, another intended workaround with CSS was:
forced-color-adjust: none;

Which tells the browser not to override the colours of that element.
It seems like Edge for iOS doesn't respect either of these options… which might actually be an obstacle they face with the Apple webkit engine they're obligated to use… However, this does seem to be a problem isolated to mobile web browsers with dark mode.
It would be good if any mobile web developers have found a way to override this override, but until then, this question cannot be marked as "answered" or closed.

In argument of not downvoting this post: This is a problem with no solution on Stack Overflow… and since the Stack Overflow website itself is affected (read the example in my question), it's noteworthy of needing a solution.

I've also been trying to work this out and have found the following.
If you go to the Edge browser on iOS and navigate to edge://flags, you can search for New Dark Mode. This states:
"If enabled, force dark mode can be applied to all web pages when possible. - iOS"
The default option is enabled, which means Edge is forcing dark mode (or attempting to) if system default is dark, or you select dark within the app, regardless of what you have set within your CSS.
When you disable this setting you can override dark mode.
So it looks like with this setting Edge isn't honouring what you put in the CSS.

Thank you for isolating the cause. You're right, this user agent configuration does fix the problem on a per-user basis. But as a developer, I can't expect visitors to have already pre-empted this problem and reconfigured this flag manually on all of their smartphones… Did you find a way to override that flag's behaviour? Or perhaps, detect the flag so that you could modify the colours in compensation (or display a warning message to the user)?

Unfortunately, no I haven't found a way to detect or override the behaviour. If it's experimental, hopefully they will see sense and allow designers to have some control. For some sites it's completely appropriate. For the one I'm working on the club colours are green and white. On Edge it keeps changing the white so it's green and dark grey, which is frustrating.

Based on your description, I'd like to know what you mean by "super-overrides" that the Edge browser's dark mode is automatically applied to all web pages, even if these pages have set light mode or something else. Please check whether there is a setting of "Dark theme for all web pages" when the dark theme is selected in the Edge appearance settings under the iOS system. If so, please turn it off and try to see if it returns to normal.

Indeed, when I say "super-overrides", I am saying as you guessed: The Edge browser's dark mode is automatically applied to all web pages, even if these pages have set light mode or something else.
There is no additional settings in the iOS Edge browser, as you speculated. It's simply: "Light" "Dark" "System default". It is possible that "System default" is the default browser option, and this causes the same super-override problem if the user's system is in dark mode.

Please refer to the answer provided by Nick Watt and check "New Dark Mode" in "edge://flags" and disable it.

That's… only a solution if it's acceptable to inform every Edge iOS user with dark mode who visits my site to go to the edge://flags and disable "New Dark Mode". You can imagine, that isn't ideal… But indeed, it's a step in the right direction.

OK. I understand what you mean. I tried to search for relevant APIs to change this phenomenon, but I didn't find any relevant resources. In addition, regarding the "Dark theme for all web pages" setting I mentioned earlier, please note that this option can only be seen when the dark mode is selected. It is because of the "Dark theme for all web pages" that this problem is caused. If none of the above suggestions apply, my only suggestion at present is that you should press "Shift+Alt+I" to submit feedback in Edge. Because through submitting feedback can let the developers modify this behavior.
